# CMake 64-bit with SFML 64-bit

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I'm trying to build a C++ project with CMake 64-bit for Windows and SFML 2.5.1 64-bit. When I run cmake on the project I'm getting an error message.

The only way I can get it to work is to change the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to point to a 32-bit version of SFML but that's not what I want.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

#project(GameOfLife)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:\\Program Files\\SFML-2.5.1\\lib\\cmake\\SFML")

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics window REQUIRED)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (GameOfLife "GameOfLife.cpp" "GameOfLife.h")

# Link SFML
target_link_libraries(GameOfLife sfml-graphics sfml-window)
```

**Error message:**

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package): Could not find a
>   configuration file for package "SFML" that is compatible with
>   requested version "2.5".
>
> The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
>
> D:/Program Files/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake, version:
>   2.5.1 (64bit)

Comment: Wether or not CMake is 64bit doesn't matter in that case. Your toolchain has to be configured to build 64bit binaries. From the error and your description of a workaround, it seems you are using a 32bit toolchain.

Comment: How do I use a 64bit toolchain then?

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem and after some investigation I understood that Stanley's comment was correct. To use a 64-bit toolchain just run:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
```

For 32-bit SFML version it is enough to run simply: `cmake ..`

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me on CLion, in my case I downloaded SFML for MinGW-64, but the default toolchain was configured to Visual Studio.

I solved this by going to File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Toolchains, clicking on MinGW and then the up arrow, making MinGW the defaut toolchain.